# Can you create a whitelist of stylecop rules instead of a blacklist?

Tags: stylecop, stylecop-plus

I'm working on a project which is using StyleCop to police its coding policies. From working on other projects, I have StyleCop+ rules installed. Because StyleCop runs all the rules it can find, the additional rules are running on my local builds, causing extra warnings for me to filter to reach the ones I genuinely need to fix.

Is there a way to make the settings file for the project a whitelist such that StyleCop will only run the rules specified?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See the "Enabled Or Disabled By Default" section at https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists for details on using the `RulesEnabledByDefault` setting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be compatible with the settings editor tool. If I make the addition of the setting to my Settings.stylecop file, the editor still shows all rules as enabled.

Comment: If you're not already using the latest version of StyleCop, you might want to file a bug report in that case.